# convert string to multiple strings

Tags: java, string

Stuck on this little project. Can't figure out how to split a String into multiple strings inside a String[].

Example:

```
String exampleString = "one two three four five";
String[] exmplString = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
```

What I have:

```
static File interfacepath;
FileReader fr;
BufferedReader br;
static String currentLine;
static String[] parseableLine;
Integer lineNumber;

public void readFile(Integer interfaceID) throws IOException {

    interfacepath = new File("data/csgui/interface_" + interfaceID
            + ".csgui");

    fr = new FileReader(interfacepath.getAbsolutePath());

    br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    br.read();

    getLine(1);
}

public static void getLine(Integer lineNumber) throws IOException {

    try (LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(
            interfacepath))) {

        for (String line = null; (line = lnr.readLine()) != null;) {

            if (lnr.getLineNumber() == lineNumber) {

                currentLine = line;
                parseableLine = currentLine.split("\\s+");

                System.out.println(parseableLine);

        }
            System.out.println(currentLine);

    }

}
}
```

When I run the application it returns:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@5bcf4b61
 testTable Table 1280 720 350 350 1
```

& What I'm having troubles achieving:

```
{testTable, Table, 1280, 720, 350, 350, 1}
testTable Table 1280 720 350 350 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could use [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "testTable Table 1280 720 350 350 1";
    String[] strArr = str.split("\\s+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArr));
}
```

Output is

```
[testTable, Table, 1280, 720, 350, 350, 1]
```

Because the [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) `"\\s+"` matches one or more white space characters.

**Edit**

Based on your updated code,

```
System.out.println(parseableLine);
```

Should be

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseableLine));
```

You get `[Ljava.lang.String;@5bcf4b6` (and need [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object[]%29)) because Java arrays do not override `toString()`

Answer (score 1):

[`.split(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) is exactly what you're looking for, assuming there is always at least one space between each string you want to split.

```
public static String[] splitBySpace(String s){
    return s.split("\\s+");
}
```

Comment: Use `return s.split("\\s");` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well everyone used [`java.lang.String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) so i have used [`java.util.StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

```
String exampleString = "testTable Table 1280 720 350 350 1";
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(exampleString," ");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
     list.add(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
 }
String str[] = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(str));
```

The constructor of StringTokenizer accepts the string to be tokenized along with the delimiters.

Comment: From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html): *`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.*

Comment: yes i agree with you just tried in a different way thats it

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your

```
return new String[] { sb.toString()};
```

to

```
return sb.toString().split("\\s");.
```

You `sb.toString()` returns `testTable Table 1280 720 350 350 1` will [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) by space and return as an array.